# heteroskedasticity in logit/cox

Tags: logistic, stata, heteroscedasticity, cox-model, robust

I am using a logit and a cox proportional hazard model for my analysis, and the newest version of Stata.

I have found that there are no tests to check for heteroskedasticity for logit/probit models, and I cannot find a test for the cox proportional hazard. However, I do suspect that there is correlation between my errors.

I am using Stata and my code is essentially:

```
stset Y, failure(censor), [pw=weights] stcox X1##X2 X1##X3, vce(robust)
```

- What should one do in such a case where heteroskedasticity is suspected?
- What does it mean to include the robust option? (The robust option is the `vce(robust)` that I've included at the end of the `stcox` function.)
- Does including the robust option take care of any problems (or introduce more problems)?

Comment: What "robust option"? Is this a feature of some software?

Comment: You can use hetprob in Stata. But dealing with it is complicated. Take a look at this trail: http://statalist.1588530.n2.nabble.com/heteroscedasticity-in-logit-probit-model-td5770451.html

Comment: @gung Yes, I am using Stata and my code is essentially:

stset Y, failure(censor), [pw=weights]

stcox X1##X2 X1##X3, vce(robust).

So, the robust option is the vce(robust) that I've included at the end of the stcox function.

Comment: @robin.datadrivers it seems that the authors of hetprob themselves are unsure of its usefulness. Their words:

"hetprob.ado represents code that James Hardin and I <jhardin@stata.com> and <wgould@stata.com>) THINK estimate such models correctly.  I want to emphasize the word THINK.  Neither James nor I have read the articles we should and, in fact, most of what follows comes from James and I hearing the words "heteroskedastic probit" and then thinking to ourselves, "what could that mean?""

At any rate, what would computing the robust st. errors in stata do to the logit/cox models?

Comment: If you find an answer to this please post it here, I face this stuff all the time.